# How to add only single value in DB with Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to add `unique values` into my `sqlite` DB.

I've tried to create unique attribute into the `.xcdatamodeld` but I didn't succeed.

This part of code adds all `terminaison` in the Table `F016Terminaison`. How can I add only `unique terminaison values`?

```
for (NSString *terminaison in [[verbe objectForKey:temps] objectForKey:@"terminaison"])
{
    F016Terminaison *newTerminaison = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"F016Terminaison" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    newTerminaison.name = terminaison;               
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` creates a new object and inserts it into
the managed object context.

If you want only unique values, you have to check first if an object with that value
already exists. That is done with an `NSFetchRequest` with a predicate like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", terminaison];
```

If you have to insert many values, then it is more effective to fetch *all* objects having
values from the new list first instead of many fetch requests.

Compare ["Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in the "Core Data Programming Guide".

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a fetch to find existing instances of an object, then add it if it doesn't exist.

eg:

```
// assumes your object has a "uniqueAttribute" and you supply a uniqueValue to test
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uniqueAttribute == %@", uniqueValue];
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if ([results count] == 1) {
    id existingObject = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    // do something with existing object
}
else if (results) {
    // create a new object
}
else {
    NSLog(@"executeFetchRequest returned error: %@ (userInfo: %@)", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
```